# how to open a html file on a click of button in new tab in html dynamically?

Tags: html, asp.net, filestream, streamwriter, system.io.file

I have to create a functionality when user click on button than an html file will generate dynamically in project name in VS and than it open in a new tab.

My code on client side:

```
 <asp:button  ID="BtnGenrateHTML" runat="server" text="   Generate HTML  " OnClick="btnAddnew_Click"  />
```

I have created a file in a directory code as follows on server side:
    protected void btnAddnew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sFileFullName;
            string sFilePath;
            string sFileName;

```
        string strHTMLGrid = "";
        strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "Dear Customer,<BR><BR> Please provide below OTP to complete registration <BR><BR> ";
        strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<BR><BR> This OTP is valid for 15 minutes.";
        strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<BR><BR> With Best Regards - Indiefy";
        This is not working //strHTMLGrid= strHTMLGrid + "<a href="abc.html/">thesitewizard.com</a>"
        sFilePath = Server.MapPath("");
       sFileName = "abc.html";
        sFileFullName = sFilePath + "\\" + sFileName;
        if (!Directory.Exists(sFileFullName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(sFilePath);
        }
        // if it exist than to delete it.
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(sFileFullName))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(sFileFullName);
        }

        // If it deleted than we need to create it again
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFileFullName, FileMode.Create);
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
           w.WriteLine(strHTMLGrid);
        }

        fs.Close();
    }
```

How to open my `abc.html` file on a click of button? Please guide me what to do.

This is not working on server side:

```
  strHTMLGrid= strHTMLGrid + "<a href="abc.html/">thesitewizard.com</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set target attribute of anchor [a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag tag to [_blank](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) to open the link in new tab.

```
<a href="abc.html" target="_blank"></a>
```

You are using double quotes within double quotes that would result in error, you need to escape double quotes with backslash as given below.

```
strHTMLGrid= strHTMLGrid + "<a href=\"abc.html\" target=\"_blank\"></a>";
```

**Edit** The button seems not in abc.html and you are trying to add anchor in abc.html that will open page abc.html This is not what you probably looking for. If you have button in some other html file say test.html and want to open abc.html from this then change button to anchor and give it style sheet to look like button.

Change

```
<asp:button  ID="BtnGenrateHTML" runat="server" text="   Generate HTML  " OnClick="btnAddnew_Click"  />
```

To

```
<a href="abc.html" target="_blank">Generate HTML</a>
```

If you want to use button then you can use window.open

```
 <asp:button  ID="BtnGenrateHTML" runat="server" text="   Generate HTML  " 
  OnClick="btnAddnew_Click" OnClientClick="window.open('abc.html', '_blank'); return false;" />
```

Comment: strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<a href=\"abc.html\" target=\"_blank\"></a>";                                                                                                                This is not working Adil on click of button it just refreshes not do anything..is their anything like window.open we can write here and pass the pass the url..is that possible on code behind..please let me know.Thanks

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "fncpopup();", true);                            on client side and than made a function                       function fncpopup() {
          window.open('abc.html', '_blank');
      }                  This worked for me awsome thanks

Comment: But this wont open on button click? you can run this script on button by binding click event on button as given in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change it to

```
strHTMLGrid= strHTMLGrid + "<a href='abc.html'>thesitewizard.com</a>"
```

Comment: Kate Thanks for reply but this code just refreshed the page..is their any method i can open the html file in window.open.Thanks for reply

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "fncpopup();", true); on client side and than made a function function fncpopup() { window.open('abc.html', '_blank'); } This worked for me awsome thanks –